# Adding functionality to individual list items with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, list, factory

I have a list of items, each of which has a delete button. When you click on the delete button, it should then show a "are you sure?" button. Currently, each list item, or project item, is in an array that I fetch from the server.

```
<button ng-class="{show: deleting}"> are you sure? </button>
```

however, each item needs to have this boolean "deleting" in order to show whether the user is thinking of deleting the project item. Should I just add a boolean variable "deleting" to each list item?

If I do that, I don't want it living on the server, should I remove it before syncing?

Comment: And how will the user be able to select "No", when asked the "are you sure"-question?

Comment: I don't really get what your question is. If you don't want a variable on the server side, don't send it to the server - it is as simple as that and you already basically said so yourself. Having a deleting variable seems like a way to go or you could write your own directive. The problem you are describing is quite trivial.

Comment: @dirkk sorry if it seems trivial, I'm having a hard time phrasing what I'm trying to say so I chose a simple example. Essentially I'm trying to find a clean way to add variables to a model that will be ignored whenever I sync.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to use a variable on the client side only, without posting it to the server, you should use te variable with the $$ sign before it.
For Example:

```
<button ng-class="{show: $$deleting}"> are you sure? </button>
```

When you post your json to the server using the angular.toJson() function, it converts the json to a string, ignoring all properties that begin with the $$ char.
The same behavior is by all angular functions (equals and etc.)

Comment: except you should never use $ and $$ in variable and function names in user scope - angularjs reserves those names.

Comment: if any time AngularJS adds $$deleting to the $scope variable this code will fail. A field called $$deleting is not entirely impossible considering AngularJS 2.0 data persistence features. at least call it something nonspecific like $$myHackyFieldDeleting

Answer (score 1):

The simples approach is to have a 'ToBeDeleted' collection in the model and two methods to a) push item, b) check if it is in the collection. something like this (might not run, I am not able to test the code, but the approach should be working)

```
function Ctrl($scope) {

   $scope.items = [ {id:1, title: 'item1'}, {id:2, title: 'item2'}];

   $scope.toDelete = [];

   $scope.softDelete = function(item) {
      $scope.toDelete.push(item);
   }

   $scope.isDeleted = function(item) {
     return $scope.toDelete.indexOf(item) > -1;
   }
}



<ul ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{item.title}}
      <button  ng-click="softDelete(item)" ng-hide="isDeleted(item)">Delete</button>
      <span  ng-show="isDeleted(item)">Item is about to be deleted</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a possible solution.

```
function Main() {
  this.items = [{
      name: 'first',
      examples: [
          {name: 'first sub1'},
          {name: 'first sub2'}
      ]},{
      name: 'second',
      examples: [
          {name: 'second sub1'},
          {name: 'second sub2'}
      ]}
  ];

    this.addExample = function(item) {
        item.examples.push({name: 'new item'});
    };
}
```